# Why was this question deleted?

Tags: discussion

I was surprised to see [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/90445/4512) question deleted by a mod.  It was about whether loudspeakers need FCC certification.  It wasn't a great question, but I didn't think it was outright bad in the sense of warranting deletion either.  Nobody had downvoted the question (or upvoted either) or voted to close it.  Nothing inflammtory was said.  What is going on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The OP requested for its deletion, I didn't see any particular reason not to do it. However, since you wrote the only answer, if you think it's a valuable contribution I can undelete it.

Comment: I'm not concerned about my answer.  I was just wondering what happened.  Usually the reason for deletion by a mod is obvious enough, but in this case I was puzzled and was wondering if there was some site policy or whatever that I was missing.

Comment: @OlinLathrop once someone answers a question with at least one upvote the OP of the question cant delete and has to flag a mod to ask.